# Python lxml and stdin

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have a xml file, book.xml (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271(VS.85).aspx)

I would like to cat books.xml and get all book ids and genres for the book id.

Similar to

```
cat books.xml | python reader.py
```

Any tips or help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Upvote because lxml documentation is a mess.

Comment: python reader.py books.xml -- Less typing and more efficient. Use sys.argv.

Comment: That works great until you want to connect it to a program that outputs an xml file to stdout.

Answer (score 12):

To read an XML file from stdin, just use `etree.parse`. This function accepts a file object, which can be `sys.stdin`.

```
import sys
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse(sys.stdin)

print ( [(b.get('id'), b.findtext('genre')) for b in tree.iterfind('book')] )
```